# Can a Fathomless Warlock move their Tentacle of the Deeps without attacking?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, warlock

In Tasha's Cauldron of Everything, a warlock with the Fathomless patron can summon a Tentacle of the Deeps, whose description includes the line

> As a bonus action on your turn, you can move the tentacle up to 30 feet and repeat the attack.

"Can...and" seems to suggest that you must do both: move and attack.  "Up to 30 feet" means you could move it 0 feet and repeat the attack, but can you move the tentacle without attacking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If nothing else, the tentacle can always attack an empty space (you need to have this ability so that you can make attacks into spaces you *think* might have a hidden enemy), so even if forced to “attack” there, you could easily choose to avoid having that attack *do anything*. So I think it’d take a really pedantic DM to make you attack if for some reason you didn’t want to—and any DM suggesting that lacking something to attack means the tentacle can’t move is simply wrong.